# Asynchronous execution of scala program in spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have noticed that my scala program doesn't work as expected.

Basically, it connects by jdbc with one database and calls to one stored procedure, which load a table with, for example, 1000 rows (one by one).

The next step in my scala program is read that table and do some calculations. Here is where the problem arises, because it reads less rows (for example, about 30) instead of the 1000.

This evidently points that the distribution of the application into the cluster by spark is not waiting properly to let the SP finish its job and it carries on with the next instruction before expected.

I have added a `Thread.sleep(10000)` and the situation improves, but I don't like at all use that workaround to solve this problem.

I have tried also to execute the application with just one Executor and the issue persists.

Someone of you guys have had this issue too? How did you resolve it?

Thanks in advance

---

Sample Code:

```
// sp which generates 1000 records in one table in database
mMeta.getConnection().prepareCall("{call " + mMeta.getDatabaseName + ".[dbo].SP_Create1000rows}")

// method which grabs the rows from database created in previous code
Process1000rows()
```

The method Process1000rows gets about 40 rows, because it's not waiting for the stored procedure to be done.

However, if I add a `Thread.sleep(10000)` between both instructions, the method takes the 1000 rows generated by the SP.

Hope it's clearer now...

Comment: Hard to say w/o a code sample. Most probably you you don't consume the result of the remote computation. Each manipulation with an `RDD` must finish with a terminal action (`collect`, `count`, etc). Without a terminal action in general no actions will be executed.

Comment: Hi @simpadjo, thanks for your anser, I am gonna add a sample, but I am afraid it won't be more usefull than the description, give me a while...

Comment: Why is it even marked with apache-spark? You don't seem to use any Spark constructs, and without these it is just a normal Scala app.

Comment: Yes, the "spark part" comes after, because the rows contains a query that will be launched by spark to load the data into the cloudera cluster

Comment: and... @user10465355, it's a normal scala app, but executed with spark-submit, so it's related.